# 12V Arduino Dual Bridge to supply at least 5A

Tags: arduino, motor, ros, h-bridge

I am looking for a 12V Dual Motor Controller that can supply at least 5A per channel for two 12V motors, and that can be used with an arduino. Do you know of any product with those specs?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, shopping questions are [off topic](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

This one may be a nice board for you
http://www.pololu.com/product/2502

they say it is unavailable, but you may find something..

or just take two of them:
http://www.pololu.com/product/1451

Comment: I purchased the MC33926 Motor Shield, but for some reason I cannot read the current of my motors. It gives me garbage. I used the demo file from Pololu. Is there any special activation that needs to be done on one of the pins?

I am using this library:

https://github.com/pololu/dual-mc33926-motor-shield

Comment: No, the demo file should work without any changes.
What do you mean by "garbage"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several products that can independently drive two DC motors at 12 V and 5 A, which can be used with an Arduino.

[OpenCircuits has a list of motor drivers](http://www.opencircuits.com/motor_driver), some of which meet your criterial.

[Sparkfun carries many motor drivers](https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/179) that meet your criteria, including the "Monster Moto Shield", the "T'Rex Robot/Motor Controller", and several Pololu drivers.

[Robot Power carries many motor drivers](http://www.robotpower.com/catalog/) that meet your criteria.

Have you heard that shopping questions are [off-topic](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site?

Comment: yes, I've heard.